# Find the largest sum of contigous elements of an array in $\Theta(n) $

Tags: algorithms, asymptotics, recursive-algorithms

For example, with the input array $[1,3,-5,7,-12,4,-1,5]$ the output is $8$ because $[4,-1,5] $ produces the largest sum. I think the answer must lie in some kind of back tracking algorithm, but I can't quite it out (meaning I've come nowhere close). I tried taking the maximums of adjacent pairs, but the resulting algorithm does not seem to work. Just brute forcing it is at least $\Omega (n^3) $, and I don't see any obvious improvements from that algorithm.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: If you reformulate problem in terms of partial sums then you need to find two indexes i>j such that a[i] - a[j] is maximal. Then you need to apply standard "method of two pointers".

Comment: Maybe it is be useful to see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_subarray_problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $a(n)$ denote the sum of the first $n$ elements. You want to maximize $a(i)-a(j)$ where $i> j$. While you are computing these sums, keep track of the smallest one that appears, i.e. let $b(n)=\min\{a(i):i\le n\}$. Then for each $a(n)$ you compute, compute
$$d(n)=a(n)-b(n-1)$$
and store the maximum of this value. When you reach the end of the array this value will be your max. That is, if $S$ is the max and the array is of size $m$,
$$S=\max\{d(n): 1<n\le m\}$$
Clearly you only loop through the array once and only need to store three variable. I take it the details can be filled in where necessary (I am typing on my phone so I am keeping it short).